Female lead book series with Chinese dragons, superheroes, and shadow powers
I read the first two books in a relatively new series nearly a decade ago about a world with super heroes and one of them was a British character named something like Mr. Mystery (but not that) who could call up shadow beings to help him fight and rode a motorcycle. However the character was in fact a woman who was portraying her grandfather and was looking for him.
Then she also learned about her powers from a Chinese dragon who was a member of a family of 9 Chinese dragons. She fell in love with him and had two kids with him. She ended up fighting and/or working with physical avatars of the Chinese zodiac.

The Dragons of Heaven by Alyc Helms:


Missy Masters inherited more than the usual genetic cocktail from her estranged grandfather. She also got his preternatural control of shadows and his enduring legacy as the legendary vigilante superhero, Mr. Mystic.
After a little work, the costume fits OK, but Missy is far from experienced at fighting crime, so she journeys to China to seek the aid of Lung Huang, the ancient master who once guided her grandfather. She becomes embroiled in the politics of Lung Huang and his siblings, the allegedly mythical nine dragon-guardians of all creation.
When Lung Di—Lung Huang's brother and mortal enemy—raises a magical barrier that cuts off China from the rest of the world, it falls to the new Mr. Mystic to prove herself by taking down the barrier.

The superhero is Mr. Mystic not Mr. Mystery and he's Missy's grandfather. She has taken over his role. Missy does ride a motorcycle but it gets blown up by the villain Lao Chan in the first chapter.
I found it by Googling for superheroes chinese dragon fantasy site:goodreads.com/book/show/ and the book was the top hit.

Nice. I may have to check that one out.

For pity's sake, thank you! I ran through a bunch of Google searches and never got close!
